# how to have multiple optional arguments in a user defined function in VBA/ Excel

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I need to develop an UDF for checking a cell value against several possible entries to check whether the cell is equal to any of those values or not. As you see I have an idea regarding how to do this check. But coding the function in a way that can accept multiple optional entries in not clear for me. for instance I am looking something dynamic like CONCATENATE in EXCEL { CONCATENATE( text1, [ text2, ... text_n ] )}.  My code for such function with 5 optional argument is as follow:

```
Function IfAmong(TextToCheck As String, Text1 As String, Optional Text2 As String, _ 
    Optional Text3 As String, Optional Text4 As String, Optional Text5 As String,_ 
    Optional text6 As String) As Boolean    
    Dim dd As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dd.CompareMode = TextCompare
       dd.Add Text1, dd.Count
       If Text2 <> "" Then dd.Add Text2, dd.Count
       If Text3 <> "" Then dd.Add Text3, dd.Count
       If Text4 <> "" Then dd.Add Text4, dd.Count
       If Text5 <> "" Then dd.Add Text5, dd.Count
       If text6 <> "" Then dd.Add text6, dd.Count
    IfAmong = dd.Exists(TextToCheck)
    dd.RemoveAll
End Function
```

I want to make it relative to number of optional entries desired by the user (As said like concatenate). and also if possible make the checking of entries automatic through a loop. I tried adding the texts as an array, but not working!

```
for i =2 to Ubound(text(i))
     if text(i) <>"" then..........
next
```

I was not able to do that as well.

Thanks and regards,
M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ParamArray`. The `ParamArray` must always be the last thing to be declared and must be of the type `Variant`. It will allow you to enter as many variables as you like without having to define each one of them.

```
Function IfAmong(TextToCheck, ParamArray Text() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim txt As Variant
    Dim dd As New Scripting.Dictionary

    dd.CompareMode = TextCompare

    For Each txt In Text()
        If Not txt = vbNullString Then dd.Add Key:=txt, Item:=dd.Count
    Next txt

    IfAmong = dd.Exists(TextToCheck)
    dd.RemoveAll
End Function
```

However, I would do this using:

```
Function IfAmong(TextToCheck, ParamArray Text() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim txt As Variant
    ' Default value if not found
    IfAmong = False
    For Each txt In Text()
        ' Make sure input is text
        If TypeName(txt) = "String" Then
            ' Test if they're equal ignoring case
            If LCase(txt) = LCase(TextToCheck) Then
                ' Set to true as found
                IfAmong = True
                ' There's no point to keep searching as we've already got our answer so lets exit
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next txt
End Function
```

This way you avoid using a dictionary which could cause reference errors. Your Dictionary in your function also doesn't handle duplicate values. A Dictionary doesn't allow you to have multiple keys of the same value so as soon as you have a duplicate text value your function will fall over as these are not handled.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I had a similar routine for an array function, so just was reapplying that here. Your code is better and more efficient. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Just be advised that the dim i and i in next i are not required and next i will cause error. I edited the code, but need peer review before getting applied.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I was using `For i = LBound(Text) to UBound(Text)` and forgot to change those bits when changed to a `For Each Loop` I'll edit my answer. Good spot